# WebTestCase: Use crawler to test a string

Tags: php, testing, symfony, functional-testing, web-crawler

Is there a way to use WebTestCase's Crawler on a string?
Normally, if I would like to make a test using WebTestCase, I would do something like below, using client:

```
public function testInitialPage()
{
    $client = $this->createClient();
    $crawler = $client->request('GET', '/');

    $this->assertCount(1, $crawler->filter('h1:contains("Contact us")'));
    ...
}
```

Now, I would like to know, is it possible to somehow use the crawler on a string, so it would be something like below:

```
public function testInitialPage()
{
    ...
    $crawler = Crawler::createCrawler("<h1>Contact us</h1>");
    $this->assertCount(1, $crawler->filter('h1:contains("Contact us")'));
    ...
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you import the Crawler class from the [DomCrawler](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html) component, you can use it in your test.

```
namespace Acme\Tests;

//...
use Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler;

class ContactTest extends WebTestCase
{
    public function testHeadlineOnContactUs()
    {
        $crawler = new Crawler("<h1>Contact us</h1>");
        $this->assertCount(1, $crawler->filter('h1:contains("Contact us")'));
    }
}
```